# Returning to UIViewController with LargeTitle after setting NavigationBar to be transparent

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

Sample project with the issue can be found [here](https://github.com/SRowley90/NavBarExample)

I have a requirement where I am going from a UIViewController inside a UINavigationController with large titles set to true to a UIViewController where the NavigationBar is transparent.

I have done this following numerous StackOverflow answers by setting the backgroundImage and shadowImage of the NavigationBar to be an empty UIImage instance:

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

The issue I am having is when I go back from this UIViewController to the first one the background image has gone and appears as a clear image if I set them to nil.

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
```

As can be seen in the images below.

[image: First viewcontroller]

[image: Second ViewController]

[image: Back to the first ViewController]

How can I get the NavigationBar back to the original state?

Comment: Try adding that function in `viewWillAppear` of the first `ViewController` instead of `viewWillDissapear` of the second one.

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla Issue still remains. The issue is the fact that the Image is set to UIImage() and does not default back to normal when set to nil.

Comment: it seems to be a bug, it’s probably worth reporting it. I gave it a few tries and with large titles it just doesn’t work. Works with normal titles though.

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla Thanks for you effort, yeah that's exactly my story with it, fine with smaller titles but when it's the LargeTitles it's no good.